# Get Server OS Version from RDP (Fingerprinting)

Tags: packet, remote-desktop, rdp, packet-capture, fingerprinting

- Can I get the OS version of a specific server from the RDP
  connection?
- Does the protocol respond with an OS version
- How can I    do it ?

I have tried working out many ways of understanding how the protocol works but I was not been able to find anything related to OS fingerprinting

Comment: Have you considered using WMI to obtain the version information, must you use a fingerprinting method?

Comment: I would like to know what OS is running before authentication and do it remotely with only RDP(Port 3389 by default) available.
Unless that can be done using WMI I would love to know how

Comment: Why not just connect to port 3389 and handle the request. For example connect to 3389 and handle security requirements as they come up.

Comment: The reason behind my question is to get a sample example or maybe a library that handles that in a way where I can use it to fingerprint the OS and get other meta data about the system

Comment: I would start with the documentation and post examples where your get stuck: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383015(v=vs.85).aspx